# Find if value is int dropdown box

Tags: jquery, each

Quick question.

I have a select droplist that contains items from a DB. When a user is typing into a textbox, my jQuery code loops through the select options to make sure that they are entering a unique item. If they enter the same item, that item is then selected in the select dropdown.

That works.

My issue is when the user enters a unique value, I post it via ajax to my server. However, it posts everytime I loop through the dropdown.

I know the reason for this is because my ajax code is contained in the $.each loop that loops through each item int he select list. How can I code it, so that the post action happens only once?

```
// grab current val
var cv = $(this).val();

// loop through gov bodies drp to make sure that value isn't already present
$("#drpCurrentGOVBody option").each(function () {

    if (cv == $(this).text()) {

        //value is already present
        //select it in drp down
        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');

    } else {

        //value isn't present. Add it to db    

    }

});

// post to db
$.post('ajax/school_search_results.php', {
    add_new_gov_type: true,
    data: cv,
    action: 'newgov'
}, function (data) {
    $("#drpCurrentGOVBody").html(data);
});
```

I've also attached a pic of the section in question.
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `});` at the end. Your ajax is *not* part of the `each`

Comment: Thanks. Made a quick edit of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably store the data you are sending with Ajax in a variable (outside the loop), once you run the loop check if the data equals to the new data which is being send, if not you should send it using your Ajax code, if it equals just skip the Ajax part. Also, if that variable is not defined yet you should also send it to your server using Ajax because it's probably the first time the loop is running.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks. Simple, but effective.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, this trick is also very useful for other loops you might make in the future, maybe not for sending data, but just the part you won't receive stuff. Keep it in mind, haha. :)